# Network hook iOS Substrate Tweak

Tags: ios, hook, jailbreak, cydia-substrate

I'm new writing iOS tweak, and i want to write a tweak to intercept a request to a server from an app to change the destination server.

Example:

App make a request to server A -> I intercept it, and i change the server A to server B, so the request will be made to server B, and the app will receive the response from server B.

The app is a webview, so i cant hook app's functions..
Specifically I want to change the request to a PHP script which answers some information, and i want to change this information.

Someone knows what functions should i hook?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Just edit the hosts file?

Comment: @cyrille Thanks for your answer! But i only want to modify request to specific files. For example: http://server.com/getPoints.php

Answer (score 0):

If specific to a webview, you can hook [-[UIWebView loadRequest:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest:), check the `request` data and alter it before sending it to `%orig()`.

Comment: Hi! First thanks for your help! :) But i haven't be able to get it working.. this is my tweak code: http://pastebin.com/Qur5jvSz I have use an alert to watch when this function is called, but it isn't showed never. In any application.. :( The tweak has been installed well, i see it on Cydia. i have tried with this example: http://www.andyibanez.com/create-mobilesubstrate-tweaks-ios/ and it works..

Comment: @AlbertoSegura have you tried hooking other basic methods? Maybe your whole tweak is not loaded for the specific app.

Comment: No, i haven't. Finally I have hacked the app using an XSS vulnerability which works without jailbreak :) Thanks for your help! For people with the same question, i have discovered Frida (www.frida.re), this tool seems to be useful, but i haven't tried it yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it may have the hooks you are looking for.

https://github.com/rpetrich/URLConnectionLog/blob/master/Tweak.x